# rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.19 is not reporting users that are using ttys

Tags: arch-linux, zsh, urxvt

I have some problems with urxvt v9.19, I'm not able to see myself reported in the `who` command.

My setup is:

- Archlinux: Linux arch 3.12.7-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 10 08:50:35 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU
- zsh shell
- rxvt-unicode (urxvt) v9.19
- awesome v3.5.2 (The Fox)

I tried other terminal emulators like: `termite`, `terminator` and `xterm` they are all working well. I have checked the [PKGBUILD](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/community.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/rxvt-unicode) from arch and I sow that urxvt was compiled with `utmp`.

I've used `htop` to analyze the process spawning. The process is spawned from the root process, something like this:

```
/sbin/init  
 |   
 urxvt  
  |  
  zsh
```

And if I use `w` from `urxvt` I get this:

```
 ➜  ~  w   
 22:34:41 up  1:05,  0 users,  load average: 0.11, 0.17,  
 0.50   USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
```

If I use `w` from `xterm` or `terminator` or `termite` I get this:

```
 ➜ ~  w  
 22:46:25 up  1:17,  1 user,  load average: 0.22, 0.19, 0.33  
 USER     TTY        LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT  
 starlays pts/0     22:46    0.00s  0.06s  0.00s w
```

How can I fix `urxvt` to work properly and report itself in the `w` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [urxvt Man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt):

**Login Stamp**

> **urxvt** tries to write an entry into the *utmp(5)* file so that it can be seen via the *who(1)* command, and can accept messages. To allow this feature, **urxvt** may need to be installed setuid root on some systems or setgid to root or to some other group on others.

Or, in other words:

```
  sudo chmod 4755 /path/to/urxvt
```

Comment: Hmm, you mean `chmod 755`, right? owner, group, others

Comment: @Starlays No, I mean exactly 4755. You should look up setuid root

Comment: Thank you, sad that I don't have enough reputation so I can upvote. Thank you for the extra information for SUID.

Comment: I wander if it is safe to do like sow, there is no security risk that any user will be able to start the terminal emulator as root?

Comment: @Starlays Not at all, quite the opposite. You should look up setuid on Wikipedia, the first 4 lines are all you need (too long for a comment). Notice that innocent-looking commands like *ping* have the setuid root bit set.

Comment: This is from Wikipedia, [setuid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid) article: _While the setuid feature is very useful in many cases, its improper use can pose a security risk[2] if the setuid attribute is assigned to executable programs that are not carefully designed._ This is why I have asked about security.

Comment: @Starlays Hopefully, the guy who wrote uvxrt will know his way arounf setuid.